How to convert [0-1] range pixel array to image?
I have a pixel array ranging [0-1] and want to convert it to image type.
I know PIL's Image.fromarray converts array of pixels ranging [0-255] in uint8 format but I haven't seen an alternative for [0-1] range. I want the image in that range for later CNN purposes and because of computation reasons I prefer to keep values low.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

The secret is to use an image format that supports float data, since JPEG only supports uint8 and PNG only supports uint8/uint16. Formats that support float that spring to mind are:

TIFF
PFM
OpenEXR

Personally, I would say they are in a pretty good order in terms of readability, interoperability - i.e. best at top and least widespread at bottom. OpenCV, Pillow and ImageMagick should be able to read all of those.

Let's go with TIFF, for an example:
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Generate pixel_array of floats in 0..1
pixel_array = np.random.rand(100, 100)

# Make into PIL Image, then save as TIFF
im = Image.fromarray(pixel_array)
im.save('result.tif')

# Now reload from TIFF, convert back to Numpy array
r = np.array(Image.open('result.tif'))

# Now compare and see if all values are close to original image
print(np.allclose(r, pixel_array))       # prints True


Check with exiftool:
exiftool result.tif

ExifTool Version Number         : 12.76
File Name                       : result.tif
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 40 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2024:05:31 13:50:05+01:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2024:05:31 13:50:06+01:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2024:05:31 13:50:05+01:00
File Permissions                : -rw-r--r--
File Type                       : TIFF
File Type Extension             : tif
MIME Type                       : image/tiff
Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)
Image Width                     : 100
Image Height                    : 100
Bits Per Sample                 : 32
Compression                     : Uncompressed
Photometric Interpretation      : BlackIsZero
Strip Offsets                   : 134
Rows Per Strip                  : 100
Strip Byte Counts               : 40000
Planar Configuration            : Chunky
Sample Format                   : Float          <--- YES, STORED AS FLOAT
Image Size                      : 100x100
Megapixels                      : 0.010


 

